# Why data not be written to File when use PrintWriter?

Tags: java, io

I am working with `PrintWriter` to write data to a file but it did not work as I expected. Program is built successfully but data didn't output to file. Here is my code:

```
 File source = new File("notebook.txt");
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(source);
 out.print("I hate Mondays");
```

And when I try to use another way to create `PrintWriter` object as below it works:

```
File source = new File("notebook.txt");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(source)));
out.print("I love Fridays");
```

I don't understand what is the difference in constructor of `PrintWiter`. Why didn't the first block output data to the file?

Comment: I suggest you have this the wrong way round. In any case the real issue is that you didn't close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to flush the `PrintWriter` in order to write the data to the file.  You can reach this by closing the PrintWriter`either by explicitly call the`close`method or use the`try-with-resource` statement:

```
File source = new File("notebook.txt");
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(source)) {
    out.print("I hate Mondays");
}
```

Alternativly you can use it without the `try-with-resource` statement:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(source);
out.print("I hate Mondays");
out.close();
```

Comment: It is better to just close.  That will do a flush if a flush is necessary.

Comment: No, the BufferedWriter does not do this implicitly. Otherwise what would be the point of it? Where would be the buffering?

Comment: When I use flush() it worked. But I when we need flush or not?

Comment: If you close the stream correctly than you do not need flush.